# text size adjustment on adsense ad units

Tags: google-adsense, text, advertising, size

Back in the day, on the adsense website, I was able to change both the font AND the size of the text for my text-based ads that appear on my website. Now, the option to change the size is no longer visible in google, however I can still change the font name.

Today, I ran a test and noticed that in the 300x600 ad unit, 4 text-based ads appear in the one unit, but the size of the text in each one is so tiny.

I also ran a random test with my 300x250 ad unit and the text size is fine.

Is there a way I can specifically force one large text size for all ad units, even if it means adding extra google-approved text in my adsense code?

Comment: Google is lagging behind the mobility curve with Adsense it seems. I know you did no say mobile, but the opposite is seems also true. Google is lagging behind on high resolution monitors too. Am I right??

Comment: Lately it seems that google is following microsoft with wanting to push people to use newer technology for some of their products but they don't think about the little guy much.

Comment: It is like no one there uses Google at all. They do not get it. Do not get me started with the last rounds of updates...

Comment: closetnoc, you and I need to run a rant line about technology updates. lol